# How can I use external USB camera in a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera, usb

I'm building an android app with flutter and I want to get access to an external camera in order to take pictures.

I'm currently using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin. So when I call the **availableCameras()** method, the returned list does not contain the USB camera (that according to what I read it's supposed to have **CameraLensDirection** equal to *external*).

Having that said I've also found that there's an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42413) referring to the problem that flutter can't access to external USB cameras.

Is there a workaround for this issue without re-writing the whole application using android platform?

Comment: Did u get anything new about this issue ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet. If you have.please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new package [usb_device 0.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/usb_device) but I haven't yet tested it.

This version supports only web platform.